# Superuser active is turned to False, how can I login to my django admin

Tags: python, django

Superuser active is turned to False, how can I login to my django admin.
I mistakenly turned my active to False as a superuser, now I can't login to my django admin. How can I get back superuser as active?
I have tried login but couldn't access admin

Comment: Have you tried to simply connect to the database and manually change the active variable to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start a shell session with:

```
python manage.py shell
```

then in the shell, you load the user and set it to active again:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
user = User.objects.get(username='the-username')
user.active = True
user.save()
```

Comment: >>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>> User = get_user_model
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='assurance')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'

I'm having the above error

Comment: @OghomwenOgunmwonyi: you forgot the parenthesis in `User = get_user_model()`...

Comment: I made correction, after all code was inputted I couldn't login my admin

>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>> User = get_user_model()
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='assurance')
>>> user.active = True
>>> user.save()
>>>

Comment: @OghomwenOgunmwonyi: well how do you know the user is inactive, and for example has no raw password, or is not an admin user anymore?

Comment: The username is correct. Earlier today when I logged in my admin, I mistakenly turned off active to False in admin User, saved and logged out. Now I'm trying to logged in admin and it show this error: 

Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.

Comment: so what is `user.is_staff` and `user.is_superuser` returning?

Comment: Finally got it, please edit your answer to user.is_active=True

>>> user.is_active
False
>>> user.is_active=True
>>> user.is_active
True
>>> user.save()
>>>

Comment: arre you sure you did not use `User.is_active`? (so with a capital), because assigning it twilce, makes no sense...

Comment: Everything is working fine and now I can login my Django Admin. This works for me.. Thanks

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
user = User.objects.get(username='the-username')
user.is_active = True #this made the magic
user.save()